# Cactus(Astrophytum) seedlings weather requirements

Tags: plant-care, seedlings, cactus

[image: seedlings]I live in Kerala, India, where the weather is humid dry. The temperature ranges from around 26 at night to 33 on daytime. My Astrohpytum seedlings are growing. They're 1.5 months old now. My questions are:

Do they need strong(morning to noon, and afternoon) sunlight?
Do they need good moisture content?

Right now i have 6 of them, kept in plastic containers, out of 12. All others just got narrowed into nothing. The stem becomes slim and dies off. That's what happened to the rest. Please tell me where i'm doing it wrong. Should i water it less? As far as i could understand, whenever i skip a day keeping the soil moist, one of them dies. I haven't covered them with any plastic wraps to keep the moisture. I appreciate any help given.